# Sort Python list of objects by date

Tags: python, datetime, sorting

I have a Python list called results. Each result in the results list has a person object, and each person object has a birthdate (result.person.birthdate). The birthdate is a datetime object.

I would like to order the list by birthdate with the oldest first. What is the most Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
results.sort(key=lambda r: r.person.birthdate)
```

Comment: Actually I don't think you want that `reverse=True`.

Comment: Yeah, I already removed it; had a slight brainfart about "oldest".

Comment: Just noticed some of the objects have person object set to None. I still want these results in the list. How can I do this while still sorting the others? Thanks.

Comment: I'll raise it as a new question

Comment: @shane: `results.sort(key=lambda r: getattr(r.person, 'birthday', datetime.max))`

Comment: Watch out: list.sort sorts in-place instead of returning the sorted list. Use `sorted(results, key=...)` if you don't want to mutate the original list.

Answer (score 16):

Totally agree with Amber, but there is another way of sorting by attribute (from the wiki: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting):

```
from operator import attrgetter
sorted_list = sorted(results, key=attrgetter('person.birthdate'))
```

This method can actually be even faster than sorting with `lambda`

Comment: `attrgetter()` is convenient if `'person.birdate' is passed as a variable. Otherwise the `lambda` is more flexible (e.g., what if `person` is None sometimes) and the time difference should be negligible in most cases.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: agreed, I just quoted the wiki:) I'll edit the answer