# simplifying maybe Monad

Tags: python, haskell, monads

I am trying to understand *maybe* [Monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#The_Maybe_monad) but most of the examples I saw used some language-specific feature. To ensure that I have gotten it conceptually right I thought of writing a generic implementation. Below is what I came up with.

Can someone tell if I have gotten it conceptually right? Is there a better way to generalize it?

```
def f():
    return 2

def g():
    return 4

def h():
    return 7

def i():
    return None

def bind(val, func):
    if val is None:
        return None
    else:
        return(func())

unit = 0

>>> bind(bind(bind(unit,f),i),h) #Returns nothing
>>> bind(bind(bind(unit,f),g),h) #Returns a value
>>>7
```

What if I wanted to add the values from these functions and abort if any of those was NULL; any suggestion?

Comment: Could be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507200/maybe-kind-of-monad-in-python

Comment: @Joehillen that's not at all true.  Monads can indeed be quite useful in dynamically typed languages.

Comment: @Matt Fenwick How? There aren't any types. What are you wrapping in the monad?

Comment: @Joehillen: dynamically typed languages do have types. What do you think the `type` function does?

Comment: @Joehillen Dynamic/static typing and strong/weak typing are independent of each other. You can have a strongly and dynamically typed language; Python and Ruby are both good examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're very close, but the signature of `bind` is

```
m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

So it's "unwrapping" `m` and passing the contained value to the next function. You currently have

```
m a -> ( () -> m b) -> m b
```

Since you're just ignoring the `val` bind gets, you should have

```
def bind(val, func):
    if val is None:
        return None
    else:
        return(func(val))
```

This is equivalent to `>>=` in Haskell. What you had before was `>>` which should be implemented as

```
# "ignore" bind
def ibind(val, func):
    bind(val, lambda _ : func())
```

which just happily throws away the value `bind` passes it.

To take this further, you'd have to introduce a class

```
class Maybe():
    def __init__(v):
        self.val = v
        self.isNothing = False
Nothing = Maybe(None)
Nothing.isNothing = True

def bind(val, func):
    if val.isNothing:
        return Nothing
    else:
        return(func(val.val))
```

Comment: How would you distinguish between `Nothing` and `Just Nothing`?

Comment: @Joehillen You can't, but as a conceptual example for understanding monads I think this is fine

Comment: @jozefg thank you so much for replying. I knew the general signature of bind but my confusion was (and still is) that my functions (f, g and others) don't take any input parameter so I can't do func(val), what do I do then?

Comment: @DevMaha Change your functions, so that they do take a parameter or use your functions with `ibind` rather than `bind`.