# How should I use the Optional type hint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm trying to understand how to use the `Optional` type hint. From [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), I know I can use `Optional` for `def test(a: int = None)` either as `def test(a: Union[int, None])` or `def test(a: Optional[int])`.

But how about following examples?

```
def test(a : dict = None):
    #print(a) ==> {'a': 1234}
    #or
    #print(a) ==> None

def test(a : list = None):
    #print(a) ==> [1,2,3,4, 'a', 'b']
    #or
    #print(a) ==> None
```

If `Optional[type]` seems to mean the same thing as `Union[type, None]`, why should I use `Optional[]` at all?

Comment: What is the advantage of using either Optional or Union[..., None] rather than a: list = None ? Isn't that syntaxe already self explanatory ?

Comment: @gohu - You are correct.  For keyword args, both `mypy` and IDEs are able to assume the obvious and automatically treat them as `Optional`.  See my answer below.

Comment: @Troy, though this is [not recommended](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#union-types).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional

Comment: in a nutshell: do `arg: type | None = None` for python>=3.10

Answer (score 568, accepted):

`Optional[...]` is a shorthand notation for `Union[..., None]`, telling the type checker that either an object of the specific type is required, *or* `None` is required. `...` stands for *any valid type hint*, including complex compound types or a `Union[]` of more types. Whenever you have a keyword argument with default value `None`, you should use `Optional`. (Note: If you are targeting Python 3.10 or newer, [PEP 604](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/) introduced a better syntax, see below).

So for your two examples, you have `dict` and `list` container types, but the default value for the `a` keyword argument shows that `None` is permitted too so use `Optional[...]`:

```
from typing import Optional

def test(a: Optional[dict] = None) -> None:
    #print(a) ==> {'a': 1234}
    #or
    #print(a) ==> None

def test(a: Optional[list] = None) -> None:
    #print(a) ==> [1, 2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b']
    #or
    #print(a) ==> None
```

There is technically no difference between using `Optional[]` on a `Union[]`, or just adding `None` to the `Union[]`. So `Optional[Union[str, int]]` and `Union[str, int, None]` are exactly the same thing.

Personally, I'd stick with *always* using `Optional[]` when setting the type for a keyword argument that uses `= None` to set a default value, this documents the reason why `None` is allowed better. Moreover, it makes it easier to move the `Union[...]` part into a separate type alias, or to later remove the `Optional[...]` part if an argument becomes mandatory.

For example, say you have

```
from typing import Optional, Union

def api_function(optional_argument: Optional[Union[str, int]] = None) -> None:
    """Frob the fooznar.

    If optional_argument is given, it must be an id of the fooznar subwidget
    to filter on. The id should be a string, or for backwards compatibility,
    an integer is also accepted.

    """
```

then documentation is improved by pulling out the `Union[str, int]` into a type alias:

```
from typing import Optional, Union

# subwidget ids used to be integers, now they are strings. Support both.
SubWidgetId = Union[str, int]


def api_function(optional_argument: Optional[SubWidgetId] = None) -> None:
    """Frob the fooznar.

    If optional_argument is given, it must be an id of the fooznar subwidget
    to filter on. The id should be a string, or for backwards compatibility,
    an integer is also accepted.

    """
```

The refactor to move the `Union[]` into an alias was made all the much easier because `Optional[...]` was used instead of `Union[str, int, None]`. The `None` value is not a 'subwidget id' after all, it's not part of the value, `None` is meant to flag the absence of a value.

Side note: Unless your code only has to support Python 3.9 or newer, you want to avoid using the standard library container types in type hinting, as you can't say anything about what types they must contain. So instead of `dict` and `list`, use `typing.Dict` and `typing.List`, respectively. And when only *reading* from a container type, you may just as well accept any immutable abstract container type; lists and tuples are `Sequence` objects, while `dict` is a `Mapping` type:

```
from typing import Mapping, Optional, Sequence, Union

def test(a: Optional[Mapping[str, int]] = None) -> None:
    """accepts an optional map with string keys and integer values"""
    # print(a) ==> {'a': 1234}
    # or
    # print(a) ==> None

def test(a: Optional[Sequence[Union[int, str]]] = None) -> None:
    """accepts an optional sequence of integers and strings
    # print(a) ==> [1, 2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b']
    # or
    # print(a) ==> None
```

In Python 3.9 and up, the standard container types have all been updated to support using them in type hints, see [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/). *But*, while you now *can* use `dict[str, int]` or `list[Union[int, str]]`, you still may want to use the more expressive `Mapping` and `Sequence` annotations to indicate that a function won't be mutating the contents (they are treated as 'read only'), and that the functions would work with *any* object that works as a mapping or sequence, respectively.

Python 3.10 introduces the `|` union operator into type hinting, see [PEP  604](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/). Instead of `Union[str, int]` you can write `str | int`. In line with other type-hinted languages, the preferred (and more concise) way to denote an optional argument in Python 3.10 and up, is now `Type | None`, e.g. `str | None` or `list | None`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Don't we need to import `Dict` and `List` from typing and write `Optional[Dict]` and `Optional[List]` instead of `Optional[dict]`...

Comment: @Alireza yes, and I state that in my answer already. Look for: *Side note: You want to avoid using the standard library container types in type hinting however, as you can't say anything about what types they must contain*

Comment: The importance of the side note about `list` and `dict` cannot be stressed enough. I hadn't realized this was a fact after consulting the official Python Documentation, until this discussion. Cheers to you guys for stressing this point.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever heard of such a thing.  Can someone point me towards documentation explaining further why such an avoidance is a good thing?

Comment: Funnily enough, when the new type union operator ([PEP 604](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/)) will be introduced in Python 3.10, the preferred way will get back to `Union[str, int, None]`, now written in a new fancy way as `str | int | None`, without the need to import the typing module.

Comment: @Jeyekomon: yes, but take into account that if you write any code that has to work on Python 3.9 or older you still may not be able to use that syntax, depending on where it is used. It'll be a while still before it'll be commonplace.

Comment: You can use `dict[X]` and `list[X]` on Python 3.7+ if you add `from __future__ import annotations`.

Comment: Does `Optional` imply that a `kwarg` argument can be left out of the passed kwargs when calling a function? In function `test` above: `test()` (similiar to an interface property in `TS` having `someProperty?: string`?

Comment: @coler-j: yes, `Optional` explicitly marks the argument as optional, so it can be left out of the call.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's not true. `def f(a: int, b: Optional[int])` doesn't make the call `f(2)` valid.

Comment: @quant_dev: that's not the fault of `Optional`, but of the developer marking an argument as 'optional' when it is not! Type hints do not by themselves enforce their meaning.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's not the point. The point is that Optional doesn't mean what you say it means.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed quant_dev is right, `Optional` does explicitly not mean that the argument is optional, see PEP-484 or https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional. You can complain about this being a misnomer, but that's how it is.

Comment: @quant_dev: ick, Marius is correct. `Optional` only means that the argument can default to `None`, not that it can be omitted. My mistake.

Comment: I do not think that leaving a space before and after the `=` and before the `None` is needed. See the other answer, and without the typing module, you would also just write it without spaces in between. Thus: `Mapping[str, int]]=None`, would it be good?

Comment: @questionto42: no, the spaces are not required, but the Python code style guide [recommends you use spaces there](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations).

Answer (score 72):

Directly from [mypy typing module docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#additional-types-and-the-typing-module).

> `Optional[str]` is just a shorthand or alias for `Union[str, None]`. It exists mostly as a convenience to help function signatures look a little cleaner.

**Update for Python 3.10+**

> you can now use the pipe operator as well.

```
# Python < 3.10
def get_cars(size: Optional[str]=None):
    pass
# Python 3.10+
def get_cars(size: str|None=None):
    pass
```

Comment: It should have been called `Nullable`. `Optional` is quite misleading.

Comment: Agreed. It's actually nothing to do with default arguments, which many people think of as 'optional'. I think this is the root of a lot of the confusion about it.

Comment: It's probably called that due to the influence of functional programming and this has affected other languages. Haskell's [Option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) type, Java's [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), Scala's [Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Option.html) are all good examples.

Comment: @GauthamC. Also C++ [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). It looks like a standard name in many programming languages, so I think the name is reasonable. Also, something like `Nullable` would have been more evocative for Python programmers but unacceptable for computer scientists.

Comment: @quant_dev It's definitely NOT misleading to call it `Optional`, quite the contrary.

Answer (score 15):

Note that since Python 3.10 you can simplify your code and type it like:

```
def foo(
   bar: int | None = None,
   another_bar: Callable[[int, list, float, datetime | None], str],
):
```

Answer (score 14):

While the accepted answer is the correct answer, one additional thing to note is that, *in the context of `kwargs`*, both `Optional[...]` and `Union[..., None]` are redundant and unnecessary.  If you're immediately setting your kwarg to `None`, then both `mypy` and IDEs assume the obvious and *automatically* treat the arg as `Optional[...]`.

IDE:

[image]

mypy:

[image: mypy automatic Optional]

For variables and method/function return values, `Optional[...]` is still necessary, however, as `mypy` cannot know, in those cases, to automatically assume anything.

Comment: True, but [not recommended](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#union-types).

Comment: That's only true with the option `--no-strict-optional`, though, which was the default before version 0.600.

Answer (score 5):

As already noted in several of the comments, ever since Python 3.7 it has been possible to use the new-style type annotations via a `__future__` import:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

def test(a: dict[str, int] | None = None) -> None:
   ...
```

As for automatically answering this and many other general best-practices questions, I would highly recommend using [pyupgrade](https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade) to automatically reformat your type annotations and the rest of your code with modern Python style. For a single file, after adding the `__future__` import, run `pyupgrade --py37-plus --keep-runtime-typing file.py`.

If you use Git, then `pyupgrade` can be set up as a [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade#as-a-pre-commit-hook) so that your code always stays modern. Here is the block I use:

```yaml
# Upgrade code style to the specified minimum supported Python version.
- repo: https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade
  rev: v3.3.1  # Adjust this to the latest version of pyupgrade
  hooks:
  - id: pyupgrade
    # Adjust the following to the minimum supported Python version for your project.
    args:
    - --py37-plus
    - --keep-runtime-typing
```

Note: The `--keep-runtime-typing` argument is required in case you use Pydantic, FastAPI, or other similar tools which rely on runtime typing. Otherwise this argument can be safely omitted.

Comment: Notice that `def test(a: dict[str, int] | None) -> None:` results in `TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'` when calling `test()` but `def test(a: dict[str, int] | None = None) -> None:` runs withot errors when calling `test()`.