# Optional vs Duck Typing

Tags: python, groovy

What is difference between Optional Typing in Groovy and Duck Typing in Python?

Comment: duck typing is best typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional typing refers to the Optional import from `from typing import Optional`. It allows you to specify types that must be upheld or be `None` (see: [How should I use the Optional type hint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710037/how-should-i-use-the-optional-type-hint)). Duck typing refers to a practice in python of "it it quacks like a duck and walks like a duck, then it's a duck". In other words, if you have something that is iterable, has a length, etc... then while it might not exactly be a list, you can treat it like a list. see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).