# How to annotate optional dict keys with Python 3.9 standard annotations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I'm trying to understand how to use Python 3.9 type hint to annotate a function that receives a dict with optional or multiple type values. I know that with Typing module, I can use easily `Union` and `Optional`. But I'd like to know if it is possible to achieve that using only Python 3.9 annotations. I didn't found anything on this matter on [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/).

Reference: [How should I use the Optional type hint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710037/how-should-i-use-the-optional-type-hint)

Example:

```
From Typing import Dict, Optional, Union

def foo(bar: Dict[Union[str, int], Optional[str]]) -> bool: return True
```

Should I do instead:

```
from __future__ import annotations

def foo(bar: dict[[str, int], [str, None]) -> bool: return True
```

Comment: Can't you just use `dict` instead of `Dict`?

Comment: Yes, I can use ```dict[str, Optional[str]]```. But I'd like to know if there is any way to use ```dict``` container, without  ```Typing.Optional``` or ```Typing.Union``` , for annotating keys and values.

Comment: no, `Union` or `Optional` are not standard collections.

Comment: Yes, I know.  I mean, ```dict[str, Typing.Optional[str]]```. I'd like to know if I can achieve the same without using Typing in Python 3.9

Comment: no, you can't, because `Union` and `Optional` are not standard collections.

Comment: Given ```def foo(a: dict[str, Optional[str]]): return True```, one have ```foo.__annotations__ == {'a': 'dict[str, Optional[str]]'}``` which evaluates to True

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No; the enhancements to type annotations in Python 3.9 do not include making `Optional` or `Union` builtins.  You'll still need to import those from `typing`.

As of [Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-604-new-type-union-operator), you can use the `|` operator to indicate a union type.

If you expect the dictionary to have specific key/value types, a `TypedDict` that gives different types for different values is generally a better option than using tricky union types to cover all the values in any case.

Answer (score 3):

In short, it depends on your linter. Visual Studio Code right now has a Python plugin v2020.11.371526539 which supports the following syntax.

```
from __future__ import annotations

def foo(bar: dict[str | int, str | None]) -> bool | int: 
  return True
```

IntelliSense displays a helpful preview:
[image]

And also for the return type:
[image]

For reference my selected linter is [pyre-check](https://pyre-check.org/docs/getting-started) version 857747d8246cde76501481378a6b7cf2e7072a2c and python version 3.9.0