# The correct way to default None in Python 3.10 type hinting

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

My understanding is that in Python >= 3.10, I can use `|` for default None (e.g., this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69440494/python-3-10-optionaltype-or-type-none)).

```
def abc(str | None) -> str:
    pass
```

I have the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Iterable

def winsorise_df(df: pd.DataFrame, level: float = 0.01, exc: Iterable[str] | None) -> pd.DataFrame:
    pass
```

This returns error `SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument`. However, the following works:

```
def winsorise_df(df: pd.DataFrame, level: float = 0.01, exc: Iterable[str] | None = None) -> pd.DataFrame:
    pass
```

My interpretation is `Iterable[str] | None` tells Python that `exc` can be an `iterable` or `None` but I need to actually set the default value as None?? I would have thought because `Iterable[str] | None` is interpreted as `Optional[Iterable[str]]`, it's implicit that default value is None. What is the correct way to set default value to None?

Comment: If you try running your first code snippet you will see that this does not work (besides the fact that the argument name is missing). This does not define the default value, it is only a type annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would have thought because `Iterable[str] | None` is interpreted as `Optional[Iterable[str]]`, it's implicit that default value is `None`.

You think wrong. It's not. You need to specify the default value.

Comment: ... the reason being that the type annotations don't affect the actual values, such as, here, the default value None.