# Can we use `bool or None` instead of Union[bool, None] for type annotating?

Tags: python, type-annotation

I'm using python3.8 and have a variable which can be `True`, `False` or `None`. For type-hinting this variable I know I can use `Union` for variables where they may have divergent types. But personally I don't prefer using `Union`. I think it's easier to use the newer python syntax `bool | None` but it's not available in `python3.8` (I think it's for 3.9 or 3.10). I want to know is it correct to use `bool or None` for this scenario?
At first I thought it's wrong, because `bool or None` will be eventually executed and become `bool`.

```py
>>> bool or None
<class 'bool'>
```

But pycharm's type checker didn't complain about it. Is this correct?

Comment: You can use the `|` syntax in earlier Python versions if you put `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of your file.

Comment: "I want to know is it correct to use `bool or None` for this scenario?" It absolutely is not.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered on your issue youself.

```
bool or None  # returns bool type
bool | None  # just equal to Union[bool, None] for Python 3.10+ 
             # and provides cleanest syntax for Type Hinting
```

Sure you can't use this in Python 3.9 or lower, because this structure (bitwise or) is not implemented. If you exactly wants to use type hints in Python 3.8, you have to use ***typing.Union***

Comment: You can read https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#types-union for more details

Answer (score 1):

@smnenko's answer is correct, but even in Python 3.10 you can also do

```py
from typing import Optional

x: Optional[bool]
```

`Optional[T]` is the same as `Union[T, None]`.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is more canonical.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are correct. `T | None` is the canonical way. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69440494/python-3-10-optionaltype-or-type-none.

Comment: good to know, thanks, I'll adjust the answer