# Binary Tree Transversing

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, binary-tree

I'm really new to coding and was stuck at one of the Leetcode problems on Binary Tree Transversing.

Can anyone please explain what the following line of code means:

```
def preorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
```

From what I understood, the core was trying to define a function pre-order traversal and a class TreeNode was defined earlier. However I was not able to get what root: Optional[TreeNode] and ->List[int] meant.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps reading documentation would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps, you can ignore the type hints in that function declaration. If you change it to this, it will still work:

```
def preorderTraversal(self, root):
```

The [type hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5) are helping editors (and you) to know the expected type of parameters and of the function's return value:

- [`Optional`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710037/how-should-i-use-the-optional-type-hint): this means the value could be `None`
- `TreeNode`: this means the value is an instance of the class `TreeNode`. [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-preorder-traversal/) provides its definition in a comment block in the original code template you get to work with. It is indeed predefined.
- [`List[int]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/type-hinting-a-collection-of-a-specified-type): this means the returned value should be a list, and the list elements should be integers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! It really cleared the questions I had