# Python Sorting a List of Namedtuples

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort this by `time` and I have no clue where to start.

```
[
    A(id=u'BLI52E', time=datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 30, 9, 52, 49, 209102)),
    A(id=u'DHCS4J', time=datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 30, 9, 53, 36, 495319)),
    A(id=u'4HMS4J', time=datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 30, 9, 53, 16, 395329)),
    A(id=u'GFTS4J', time=datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 30, 9, 53, 36, 295319)),
    A(id=u'BH244K', time=datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 30, 9, 53, 23, 591319)),
]
```

Comment: It looks like a list (of `A` objects) to me. Isn't it?

Comment: You need more info.  What information do you want to sort on?  Then just past a comparison function to the list.sort() method.  Also I agree with falsetru it's exactly what I imagine a list of A's to look like.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'm trying to sort by time

Comment: Thanks falsetru and demented hedgehog for leading me to the solution :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055812/sort-python-list-of-objects-by-date

Comment: Please mark the correct answer bellow and if you wanted in reverse you should mention that in the question... no need to edit questions with answers..

Comment: I believe this is a list of namedtuples, https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Comment: Please include the definition of `A`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to sorting list of namedtuples by field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087905/pythonic-way-to-sorting-list-of-namedtuples-by-field-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sorting on "keys" of named tuples contained within a list, you could do the following:

```
spam = [
            A(id=u'BLI52E', time=datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 30, 9, 52, 49, 209102)),
            A(id=u'DHCS4J', time=datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 30, 9, 53, 36, 495319))
       ]
spam.sort(key=lambda x:x.time)
```

Extracted from here:
[Python: Tuples/dictionaries as keys, select, sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878881/python-tuples-dictionaries-as-keys-select-sort)

Comment: Thanks happyhamburger for taking the time to answer my question.

I found this to be the best solution
`list.sort(key=lambda r: r.time, reverse=True)`

Comment: Hehe, yeah had to change my answer there ;)

Comment: could you just remove the "regular tuple sorting" because this isn't a tuple `tuples use parentheses and lists use square brackets.`

Comment: Fair point, I guess what I meant to show was the difference in sorting a list of standard tuples, as opposed to sorting a list of named tuples. In other words using a traditional tuple, you could order them by specifying the index to order on (since they have no key). However, since you are using named tuples, the treatment is slightly different.